# What is the most convenient component to create image distance annotations in WPF?

Tags: c#, wpf, image, annotations, line

I need to be able to add annotations over an image in my app.
One of the annotation types is linear: I should be able to draw a line with the text which automatically shows the line length (distance). The annotation should be editable (so after a user creates it they might need to move one of the line ends - the text with the length should be changed).

As for now the most convenient WPF control to implement this task is InkCanvas.
I can add Children to them, I can select the children and move/resize them. But, for instance, its selection tool does not look very convenient from the user perspective.

So the question is: Is there a better free control/framework to implement this task in WPF?

Comment: What did you end up going with?